# Can't Run Spark CassandraTest Example

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark

I started getting this problem when trying to write my own Spark application, and eventually backed off to just trying to get the examples running - which I've been unable to do.

I ran `bin/run-example CassandraTest localhost localhost 9160` and got the following error. (I ran `bin/run-example CassandraTest localhost 9160` before that, but got an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`, so I just put something into the first position)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected
at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.AbstractColumnFamilyInputFormat.getSplits(AbstractColumnFamilyInputFormat.java:113)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD.getPartitions(NewHadoopRDD.scala:90)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:204)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:202)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:202)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MappedRDD.getPartitions(MappedRDD.scala:28)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:204)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:202)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:202)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.FlatMappedRDD.getPartitions(FlatMappedRDD.scala:30)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:204)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:202)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:202)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MappedRDD.getPartitions(MappedRDD.scala:28)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:204)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:202)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:202)
at org.apache.spark.Partitioner$.defaultPartitioner(Partitioner.scala:59)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.reduceByKey(PairRDDFunctions.scala:370)
at org.apache.spark.examples.CassandraTest$.main(CassandraTest.scala:100)
at org.apache.spark.examples.CassandraTest.main(CassandraTest.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.launch(SparkSubmit.scala:292)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:55)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

My configuration:

- spark-1.0.0-bin-hadoop2 (a binary distribution, with source for the examples, but no `sbt` or build files). I didn't make any changes to any files in this folder.
- Running cassandra 1.2.16 in a separate process (started using `sudo bin/cassandra start` from the unziped binary package that I downloaded). I've also tried 1.2.6 and 2.0.6.
- Oracle Java 7 on OSX 10.9

I'm hoping someone can get me help so I can get past this error and start using Spark with Cassandra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two versions of hadoop at play here. One packages with the binary distro of Spark and one embedded in Cassandra: `org.apache.cassandra.hadoop...`

You need to match both versions in order to have a working system. I'm not sure which hadoop version in supported with Cassandra, but given your issues are with `spark-1.0.0-bin-hadoop2`  I'd suggest you try a Spark distro with Hadoop v1.